# Getting error while creating node in neo4j using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, neo4j

My Code!!

```
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser =require('body-parser');
var app=express();
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", neo4j.auth.basic("Novasys", "123456"));
var session = driver.session();
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  session
  .run('MATCH (n:Movie) RETURN n LIMIT 30')
  .then(function(result){
    var moviearr = [];
    result.records.forEach(function(record){
      moviearr.push({enter code here
        id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
        title: record._fields[0].properties.title,
        released: record._fields[0].properties.released
      });
    });

    session
    .run('MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
    .then(function(result2){
      var personArr = [];
      result2.records.forEach(function(record){
      personArr.push({
        id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
        name: record._fields[0].properties.name
      });
      });
      res.render('index', {
      movies: moviearr,
      persons: personArr
    });
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
});

app.post('/movie/add',function(req,res,next){
      var title = req.body.title;
      var released = req.body.released;

      session
      .run('CREATE(n:Movie {title:{titleParam}, released:{releasedParam}}) RETURN n.title',{titleParam:title, releasedParam:released})
      .then(function(result){
          res.redirect();
        session.close();
      })
      .catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
   });

      res.redirect('/');

});
app.listen(4000);
console.log('Server started on port 4000');

module.exports=app;   **strong text**
```

getting error!!

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
   at B:\nodejs\newp\app.js:75:30
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at next (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
   at Route.dispatch (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
   at Function.process_params (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
   at next (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
   at serveStatic (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (B:\nodejs\newp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Can anyone help me in solving this. I am new to node js as well as neo4j.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

☼ Hello,

Do you have a label "Person" in your Neo4j database ?

```
 session
    .run('MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
```

Have you tried with :

```
session
        .run('MATCH (n:Actor) RETURN n LIMIT 25')
```

I think you took this exemple [here](https://youtu.be/snjnJCZhXUM?t=22m50s), but they use the labels "Movies" and "Actors"

Comment: ☼ Also, it is not compulsory to add "LIMIT 25". This will show you 25 entries of the result, or less if you have, in this case, less Actors.